# Vue ant design select in table

Tags: vue.js, antd

I'm adding select component to table, and now i would like to get selected items, but if i add v-model to a-select all my selects select same value, another idea to get index of row and add to select Array, but idk how to get rowIndex in @change event.
How can i get index of row or get for each a-select it's own v-model?

```
<a-table
        :columns="columns"
        :dataSource="data"
        :scroll="{ x: 'max-content' }"
        :pagination="{ pageSize: 9 }">
        <template slot="Client">
            <a-select v-model="selected" style="width: 200px" @change="handleChange">
               <a-select-option v-for="client in getProjects" :key="client" :value="client">
                  {{client}}
               </a-select-option>
            </a-select>
        </template>
</a-table>
```

Answer (score 0):

At least i need to add a slot-scope in my slot, to achives it

```
<a-table
                :columns="columns"
                :dataSource="data"
                :scroll="{ x: 'max-content' }"
                :pagination="{ pageSize: 6 }">
            <template slot="Client" slot-scope="text, record">
                <a-select v-model="selected[record.key - 1]" style="width: 200px">
                    <a-select-option v-for="client in getProjects" :key="client" :value="client">
                        {{client}}
                    </a-select-option>
                </a-select>
          </template>
```